# Calculate cumulative average for the latest entries

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate cumulative average values of `value` over `id`s for each date so that only the last `id`s were taken into account. For example, the initial table looks like this:

```
id  value   y   m   d
1   1   2020    3   10
2   2   2020    3   10
3   1   2020    3   11
2   4   2020    3   11
```

And I want to produce:

```
date    average
2020-3-10   1.5
2020-3-11   2
```

Here, the cumulative average for date `2020-3-11` is calculated as (1+4+1)/3 - takes `value`s from the first and last 2 rows.

I have tried to solve the problem this way:

```
SELECT date_parse(cast(c.y*10000+c.m*100+c.d as varchar), '%Y%m%d') as date, avg(s.value) as cum_aver FROM 
(SELECT *
  FROM ( 
  SELECT id, value, date_parse(cast(y*10000+m*100+d as varchar), '%Y%m%d') as date,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_parse (cast(y*10000+m*100+d as varchar), '%Y%m%d') DESC, id DESC) rn) from table
 WHERE rn = 1) s
 join table c ON 
 s.date <= date_parse (cast(c.y*10000+c.m*100+c.d as varchar), '%Y%m%d')
 group by c.y, c.m, c.d
```

But it did not give me the desired output.

Comment: You've tagged both MySQL and SQL Server? Are you using both? Otherwise please correct the tags.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Why the formula `(1+4+1)/3` instead of `(1+4)/2`? You are including a value from a different date.

Comment: I am including the value from the different date because I want to get averages for all the latest distinct `id`s (dates are the current considered date plus all the previous dates - aka moving average). This I presume is the definition of the cumulative average if I am right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the average of the most recent value for each id is quite tricky.  The idea is to take the most recent value for each id and divide by the number of different ids.

And this is also tricky.  To get the sum, one method is to keep the first value and then take successive differences.  The sum of these differences is the sum at any point in time.  The number of different ids -- well, just count the first one you see.

```
select y, m, d,
       (sum(sum(value - prev_value)) over (order by y, m, d) /
        sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) over (order by y, m, d)
       ) as average
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by y, m, d) as seqnum,
             lag(value, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by y, m, d) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
group by y, m, d;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ce1390fddfbaca747f11eafba503c261) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Still don't get the question. Why is it using three values instead of two for the second date?

Comment: Thank you for such a clever solution and quick response! Was struggling with it for ages

Comment: @ali33 . . . This is one of the most interesting problems I've seen in a while.